# Почему возникает ошибка?

Tags: php

Странно, я делаю

```
$db->Query(SELECT data FROM table_backup WHERE id=$id);
$row=$db->RowArray();
$data=unserialize($row['data']);
$db->AutoInsertUpdate("table",$data,$id);
```

Выводит ошибку не понятную мне:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'питания PS2 ATX 1FAN (1000W) , 190*150*86mm,  +5B=30A, +12B=90A, +3,3B=28A, 5VSB' at line 1 (#1064)**

после userialize $data содержит:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 23
        [id] => 23
        [1] => 90
        [cat_id] => 90
        [2] => 127
        [vendor_id] => 127
        [3] => pice
        [pice] => pice
        [4] => Блок питания PS2 ATX 1FAN (1000W) , 190*150*86mm,  +5B=30A, +12B=90A, +3,3B=28A, 5VSB=4A, Защита от перегрузки 105-150%, Входное напряжение 90-260В
        [name] => Блок питания PS2 ATX 1FAN (1000W) , 190*150*86mm,  +5B=30A, +12B=90A, +3,3B=28A, 5VSB=4A, Защита от перегрузки 105-150%, Входное напряжение 90-260В
        [5] => 
        [model] => 
        [6] => ISP1000
        [partnum] => ISP1000
        [7] => 
        [barcode] => 
        [8] => 
        [prim] => 
        [9] => 1310048629
        [data] => 1310048629
        [10] => 320.00
        [price] => 320.00
        [11] => 
        [shortstory] => 
        [12] => 
        [fullstory] => 
        [13] => 
        [photo] => 
        [14] => 1
        [statuswhs] => 1
        [15] => 0
        [status] => 0
        [16] => 0
        [payed] => 0
        [17] => 0
        [redactor_id] => 0
    )
```

я понимаю что эта за ошибка, но не понимаю почему она происходит. Подскажите плиз.

Comment: Функция
$db->AutoInsertUpdate("table",$data,$id);
строит обычный запрос INSERT или UPDATE по ключам и значениям массива, и обновляет строку $id если такая уже существует, иначе добавляет новую строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Ошибка была в классе работающем с БД. При создании строки запроса не учитывались кавычки.